# $L$ and $F$ are separable extension of $K$ and stay in the same bigger field $M$. Prove that $LF$ is separable extension of $K$.

Tags: galois-theory

$L$ and $F$ are separable extension of $K$ and stay in the same bigger field $M$. Prove that $LF$ is separable extension of $K$.

I see the solution of the finite case but in the infinite I just think but I can not write. Thank you for your help

Comment: A field extension is separable if and only if it is generated by separable elements. And actually you can easily reduce to the finite case.

Answer (score 0):

as $L$ and $K$ are separable over $K$ then all element in the set
$L\cup M$ are separable over $K $ therefore $K(L\cup M)=LM$ is
separable over $K$ this is obtained by reduction to finite case as
follows:  if $x\in K(L\cup M)=LM$ then  there is a finite $S$ set
in $L\cup M$ s.t $x\in K(S)$ and since $S$  separable over $K$ the
field extension $K(S)/K$ is finite and separable as composite of
finite  separable extension, and so $x$ separable.